# zsh: command not found: nvm

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, nvm

Recently, I've been trying to use nvm to manage node version.
I successfully installed nvm on Mac OS Catalina(10.15.6) and I can switch between version from the terminal.

However, if I try to do the same thing with the integrated terminal on VSCode, I get
`zsh: command not found: nvm`

Been looking for solutions or workaround, but there seems to be no relevant answers. Has anyone figure this out?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Close all your terminals and open again or restart the mac.

Comment: nope, that doesn't work @raven

Comment: Have you installed nvm globally? Perhaps the flag hasn't been set system wide

Comment: It could be in your terminal you use a different shell than zsh, and the nvm path was not added into zsh configure. Can you show the result of `echo $SHELL` in your terminal where it works ok?

Comment: /bin/zsh I get this

Comment: then I think the terminal emulator in VSCode somehow ignores the zsh config, please check the `echo $PATH` result in both, to see if there is anything missing

Answer (score 10):

When I installed VSCode, oh-my-zsh and NVM using homebrew I had the same issue. It appears to put wrong paths in ~/.zshrc (might be the same for bash).

Solution:

1. Open ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc
2. Create a backup of that file in case something goes wrong
3. Compare paths under the line

> `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`

3. Now you need to fix the two paths if different than those below

> `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`

> `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`

4. Type `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal depending on what you use.
5. Restart VSCode built-in terminal and see if that helped. Good luck!

Comment: yes, it looks like installing NVM using Homebrew messes up the configs. Setting the paths as mentioned here and their documents helped me to fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue after installing nvm and tried to run nvm command in VS Code terminal. This is how I solve it:

**Prerequisites**:

- macOS Sonoma v14.0
- already install Homebrew (mine is v4.1.14)

**Steps**:

- Right after installing nvm with brew, create a .nvm folder `mkdir .nvm`
- Create a .zshrc file in Home directory, same as .nvm
- Open and add this code below to the .zshrc file

> source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

- Back to terminal, execute the .zshrc by running `source ~/.zshrc`
- Restart the VS Code and try to run a nvm command

May this help you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out so I'll post an answer.

- BTW I'm a Mac user. Not really sure about windows.

The reason why I get the `zsh: command not found` error was because I had Visual Studio Code placed under the Documents directory.

It seems like VSCODE terminal works properly when it is set under the **Applications folder**.

***Make sure to place VSCode under Application folder.***

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue whereby nvm was working well on my macOS terminal (or rather iTerm), but when I tried switching node versions in my VS Code integrated terminal, I'd get: `zsh: command not found: nvm`. I had installed nvm using homebrew, which I figured out was why I was having this issue. Anyway, this is how I solved it:

1. Open up your built-in terminal or iTerm, head into your home directory, and run:

> `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.4/install.sh | bash`

2. Set up and load the Node Version Manager (nvm) environment:

> `export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm`

3. Quit VS Code, then launch it from your built-in terminal. It should now work.

Hope this helps!